# Using the SQL syntax CASE returning unknown error message "THEN1"

Tags: sql

Hi can anyone help me with the below,  I have tried changing the DEC to INT which has no effect, my system is running a DERBY syntax which `CASE` is accepted so not sure why the below isn't working.

**The error message being received is:**

> BIC00004. DAL01008. An error occurred while accessing the database.
>
> Syntax error: Encountered "THEN1" at line 1, column 416."

**My query is as follows:**

```
SELECT
    G."GROUP"
    , G."GROUP.DESC"
    , G.SIZE
    , G."SIZE.DESC"
    , G."WH.AREA"
    , G.OSQTY AS "SALES.RATIO.QTY"
    , F.QTY AS "MAX HOLDING"
    , E."DUE OUT OSQTY" AS  "OUT THIS WEEK"
    , D."OUT THIS WEEK OSQTY"
    , C."DUE IN THIS WEEK OSQTY"
    , B."CURRENT STOCK" 
    , A."ACTUAL ORDERS"
    , H.NAME
    , (CASE 
        WHEN CAST (G."WH.AREA" AS DEC) = CAST (90 AS DEC) THEN CAST (SUM(G.OSQTY) AS DEC)
        WHEN CAST (G."WH.AREA" AS DEC) = CAST (91 AS DEC) THEN CAST (SUM(G.OSQTY) AS DEC)
        WHEN CAST (G."WH.AREA" AS DEC) = CAST (93 AS DEC) THEN CAST (SUM(G.OSQTY) AS DEC)
        WHEN CAST (G."WH.AREA" AS DEC) = CAST (900 AS DEC) THEN CAST (SUM(G.OSQTY) AS DEC)
        WHEN CAST (G."WH.AREA" AS DEC) = CAST (901 AS DEC) THEN CAST (SUM(G.OSQTY) AS DEC)
        WHEN CAST (G."WH.AREA" AS DEC) = CAST (903 AS DEC) THEN CAST (SUM(G.OSQTY) AS DEC)
        WHEN CAST (G."WH.AREA" AS DEC) = CAST (904 AS DEC) THEN CAST (SUM(G.OSQTY) AS DEC)
        ELSE CAST('99999999999'AS DEC) 
    END) AS "salesratiosum"
FROM "vol.sales.ratio" G
    INNER JOIN "vol.max.holding" F
    ON (F.SIZE = G.SIZE AND F."PRODUCT.GROUP" = G."GROUP" AND F.WH = G."WH.AREA")
    LEFT JOIN "vol.due.out.this.week" E
    ON (F.WH = E."WH.AREA" AND F.SIZE = E.SIZE AND F."PRODUCT.GROUP" = E."GROUP")
    LEFT JOIN "vol.due.out.next.week" D
    ON (F.WH = D."WH.AREA" AND F.SIZE = D.SIZE AND F."PRODUCT.GROUP" = D."GROUP")
    LEFT JOIN "vol.due.in.this.week" C
    ON (F.WH = C.BRANCH AND F.SIZE = C. SIZE AND F."PRODUCT.GROUP" = C."GROUP")
    INNER JOIN "vol.current.stock.holding" B
    ON (F.WH = B.WAREHOUSE AND F.SIZE = B.SIZE AND F."PRODUCT.GROUP" = B."GROUP")
    LEFT JOIN "vol.actual.orders" A
    ON (F.WH = A.BRANCH AND F.SIZE = A.SIZE AND F."PRODUCT.GROUP" = A."GROUP")
    INNER JOIN Warehouses H
    ON (F.WH = H.WAREHOUSE)
GROUP BY 
    G."GROUP"
    , G."GROUP.DESC"
    , G.SIZE
    , G."SIZE.DESC"
    , G."WH.AREA"
    , G.OSQTY
    , F.QTY
    , E."DUE OUT OSQTY"
    , D."OUT THIS WEEK OSQTY"
    , C."DUE IN THIS WEEK OSQTY"
    , B."CURRENT STOCK"
    , A."ACTUAL ORDERS"
    , H.NAME
```

Comment: Please show the query that is giving the problem. This isn't that query.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? `"vol.sales.ratio"` looks like a really strange tablename

Comment: well its a Virtual table I created within the report writing software we use (I know hands have been slapped for the table names) the table pulls data from our U2 (Universe) data source and caches the results at a defined schedule (allowing speed for report writing and visual dashboards as they don't need to be real time when viewed) hope that makes sense?

Comment: I would suggest performing a simple `SELECT` on each table, given the tables are virtual it is possible that the error is being triggered when they are being created.

Comment: I think the `AS DEC` should be outside of the parenthesis in all of these lines `THEN CAST (SUM(G.OSQTY) AS DEC)`.  In fact, it shouldn't even be there, as it's not going to be used anyways when it gets aliased to "salesratiosum".  **Edit:** That whole case statement could use some work.  You don't need `AS DEC` anywhere

Comment: Really, a typical table names with lots of keyword use. BTW, I don't see anything wrong in your case statements.

Comment: Thanks guys, I have cleaned up my table names and removed the DEC from the CASE statement, seems to have stopped moaning now.